# How do I create a Radio Menu Item in c++?

Tags: c++, menu, radio-button, menuitem

I just started C++ and I searched online for ways to create a radio menu item, but
I'm quite confused.

Preferrable an example would help clear things up.

So, I want to be able to create a simple radio menu item like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIU95.png

but, I'm stuck on how to create a radio menu item.
So far I have this:

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    HRESULT hr;
    POINTER_INFO pointerInfo = {};

    HMENU hmenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
    HMENU hChangeMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hGesture = CreateMenu();     
    HMENU hPointer = CreateMenu();       


    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hr);

    if(changeAPI)
    {
        AppendMenu(hmenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hChangeMenu, L"API");


        **// I want this to be a radio menu item, all I know is the MF_POPUP**
        AppendMenu(hChangeMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hGesture, L"Gesture");
        AppendMenu(hChangeMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hPointer, L"Pointer"); 
        AppendMenu(hChangeMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hTouch, L"Touch");


        changeAPI = false;

    }
    //....other stuff....
```

Comment: There isn't something like a radio-button in C++, C++ is just the language itself. However, there is a radio-button in Windows, and Windows exposes it's functionality to applications using the WinAPI. If you just started doing C++ I would suggest you do console-applications first. When you feel ready for playing with GUIs I would suggest you use a wrapper for the WinAPI, pure WinAPI is a real pain. Qt or MFC would work well.

Comment: I highly recommend not using the WinAPI for a windowing system and use something easier like WxWidgets, Qt or Smart.

Comment: Ohh that is what I really meant to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "radio" logical behavior of the menu items must be provided by your code. After you have created the menu items use ModifyMenu to add/remove a check mark or bitmap to the appropriate items.

Comment: sad that WinAPI doesn't provide the radio feature, but your advice will do the job :)

Answer (score -1):

Use CheckMenuRadioItem
e.g.
CheckMenuRadioItem(m_hNoteMenu, IDM_NOTE_BREVE, IDM_NOTE_DEMISEMIQUAVER, IDM_NOTE_SEMIBREVE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
or
CheckMenuRadioItem(m_hNoteMenu, 1, 3, 1, MF_BYPOSITION);